# Using string_split and CROSS APPLY in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to write this query using LINQ to Entities and not as raw SQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM Articles
CROSS APPLY string_split(Tags, ',')
WHERE value IN ('programming', 'sql')
```

The table is something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Articles(Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Title nvarchar(max) NOT NULL, Tags nvarchar(max) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Articles (Title, Tags) VALUES ('First', 'programming,sql');
INSERT INTO Articles (Title, Tags) VALUES ('Second', 'programming,csharp');
```

UPDATE: It's possible with used-defined table-valued function that does `SELECT ... CROSS APPLY ...`

```
var tags = new[] { "programming", "sql" };
var articles = from a in db.Articles
               join awt in db.ArticlesWithTags() on a.Id equals awt.Id
               where tags.Contains(awt.Tag)
               select a;
```

Is there a way to call system table-valued functions in EF?

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is a Microsoft's extension to SQL and is using with functions in this case you should try use `Split(',')`,  `var x = articleses.Where(d => d.Title == "First").Select(d=>d.Tags.Split(','));` -This sample return string array and should look `{"programming","sql"}`

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. `Where` returns `IQueryable<Article>` and it doesn't have `Tags` property. Moreover, `String.Split` can't be translated to SQL.

Comment: @synapse You should clarify in your question that you want not LINQ to Entities (as in my answer), but LINQ to SQL (and direct invocation of `string_split`).

Comment: LINQ to SQL was completely different ORM, when you use LINQ to query Entity Framework it's called LINQ to Entities. The part that allows using `Where`, `Select` and other stuff on `IEnumerable` is called LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score -2):

Well of course it can be translated to LINQ:

```
var res = from a in db.Articles.AsEnumerable()
          from tag in a.Tags.Split(',')
          select new {
              Id = a.Id,
              Title = a.Title,
              Tags = a.Tags,    // you probably don't want this
              Tag = tag
          };
```

You, of course, should understand, that `Tags.Split(',')` wouldn't be translated into `string_split` directly. It rather be calling `SELECT` in SQL and then performing string splitting and new object creation in .NET as a result of `AsEnumerable()` call.

Comment: Obviously, the idea is to use SQL Server's table-valued function and not materialize all the results in application.

Comment: @synapse Then, your answer is no, you can't do that only via LINQ. But the question then is not about 'materializing' the results, it would be done regardless at some point, but about what is more efficient: using `string_split` in SQL query or `String.Split()` in app. I would argue that the difference is negligible.

Comment: I've kept only the essential parts in my question, the real query has `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @synapse It can be performed in LINQ and subsequently translated to SQL (if, of course, it doesn't contain `string_split` etc) before calling the `AsEnumerable()`.